# checklist-model module does not work when using ng-route

Tags: angularjs, angularjs-ng-route, checklist-model

I was trying to use [checklist-model] (https://github.com/vitalets/checklist-model) module in my app but I caught an error that I have figured out it was because of using (ngRoute) module in the same app.

```
var mainMod = angular.module('MainApp', ['ngRoute'],['checklist-model']);

mainMod.config(['$routeProvider',function($routeProvider) {

        $routeProvider
            .when("/patient-list", {
                templateUrl: "patient-list.html",
                            controller: "dbCtrl"

            })
            .when("/patientRecord", {
                templateUrl: "patientRecord.html",
                controller: "MainCtrl2"
            })
            .otherwise({
                templateUrl: "patient-list.html",
                            controller: "dbCtrl"

            })

    }

]);
```

The error:

> angular.min.js:6Uncaught Error: [$injector:modulerr]
>   http://errors.angularjs.org/1.2.24/$injector/modulerr?p0=MainApp&p1=Error%3…%20gc%20(http%3A%2F%2Flocalhost%2Ftest%2Ffiles%2Fangular.min.js%3A36%3A309)

If there is any solution for this I will be happy to know.

Thanks for your efforts

Comment: The second parameter is supposed to be an array of all of your dependencies.  Try angular.module('MainApp', ['ngRoute', 'checklist-module']);

Comment: Also, if you do your development with the unminified version of the angular.js library, you will get more useful error messages.

Comment: thank you sir it works now :)

Comment: Great!  I went ahead and posted it as an answer then.  Glad you got it working.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The second parameter is supposed to be an array of all of your dependencies.  Try `angular.module('MainApp', ['ngRoute', 'checklist-module']);` instead.

Also, using the unminified version for your development work will produce more useful error messages.